# foreach in rich data table

Tags: jsf, richfaces, richdatatable

i am trying to display  list in data rich table my code is

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{form.tableResultat}"
                            var="rows"  style="width:700px" >

                            <rich:columnGroup columnClasses="#{rows.classLevel}">

                        <c:forEach var="index" begin="0" end="3">
                            <rich:column colspan="#{rows.columns[index].colSpan}" rowspan="#{rows.columns[index].rowSpan}">
                            <t:outputText value="#{rows.columns[index].colSpan}"  />
                            </rich:column>
                            </c:forEach>
                            </rich:columnGroup>

                            </rich:dataTable>
```

the problem is that thevar index it is null but when i do replace ${index} it display the value and i can't do ${index} in my code how i fix this and what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

first:
you have a typo in the line

```
<t:outputText value="#{rows.columns.[index].colSpan}"  />
```

I think this should look like:

```
<t:outputText value="#{rows.columns[index].colSpan}"  />
```

have you tried to remove the c:forEach loop and do it hard coded?

Comment: <rich:dataTable value="#{form.tableResultat}" var="rows"  style="width:700px" >
  <rich:columnGroup columnClasses="#{rows.classLevel}">
    <rich:column colspan="#{rows.columns[0].colSpan}" rowspan="#{rows.columns[0].rowSpan}">
      <t:outputText value="#{rows.columns[0].colSpan}"  />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column colspan="#{rows.columns[1].colSpan}" rowspan="#{rows.columns[1].rowSpan}">
         <t:outputText value="#{rows.columns[1].colSpan}"  />
                            </rich:column>
  </rich:columnGroup>
     </rich:dataTable>